# What is the actual difference between Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD) and StringUtils.stripAccents(s)?

Tags: java, string, unicode, diacritics

Both methods seem to do the same job of stripping accents from a string but I'm not sure if there is some internal difference that would make one better choice over the other

Comment: I suppose you mean Apache common langs `StringUtils` ?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.954

Comment: Yes I meant the Apache common langs, sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Decomposition deals with more than just accents (called marks in Unicode), for example are the Hangul syllables U+AC00…U+D7A3.